# Unable to understand exactly what sum function is doing here

Tags: python

Yesterday I encountered a list comprehension and saw `sum(x[y])` and tried but unable to understand what exactly happening.

For creating [Lo Shu magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo_Shu_Square), I saw `sum(x[y])`, where `x` is a nested list, `y` is in range. I know only basic sum function process, I would appreciate if anyone explains above mentioned concept and other application process of sum function

```
>>> values = [list(range(1, 4)), list(range(4, 7))]

>>> values
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

>>> sum(x[y] for x in values for y in range(2))
12
>>> sum(x[y] for x in values for y in range(3))
21
```

Comment: Those are actually generator expressions. A small but subtle difference.

Comment: Try to re-write the statements without the generator expression and you might understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sum` function adds all values presented to it.

`(x[y] for x in values for y in range(2))` yields the values `1, 2, 4, 5` and
`(x[y] for x in values for y in range(3))` yields the values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

Thus you get `sum([1,2,4,5])=12` and `sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])=21`.

Read [the docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to understand how generators work.

Comment: The generator expression is iterable and yields values. It doesn't generate a list.

Comment: What is the difference? Don't they work the same way? Is it something performance related?

Comment: Yes, it's performance related. If you don't need all the values they are only created when needed.

Comment: it was helpful and thank you, actually this concepts aren't in the books(starting out with python, Automate the Boring Stuff with Python Programming, and so on).      so can u suggest me any books or any sites where i can learn much more like this?

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks for the explanation. Edited the answer.

Comment: @avimatta  Check [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonBooks) for books on Python or try one of the various python courses on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org)

Comment: @avimatta: Have you worked through the official Python tutorial? Also see [What tutorial should I read?](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F)

Comment: @avimatta There's a link to the official python tutorial on the page I linked you to, as well as links to other resources. The official tutorial is primarily designed for people who already know how to program in another language. So if you can't already program well in another language it may not be a good first choice, but you should definitely read it at some stage.